# How can standardise microarray dataset?

Tags: r

I want to convert expression level value to z-score (mean-x/sd). I have two type of samples in my microarray (Affymetrix GeneChip Human Genome U133 Plus 2.0) (normal vs case) Do I have to calculate the mean and sd for the Normal samples only and use z-score formula then do it for case samples or I have to find the mean and sd for the whole samples ?

```
            ID_REF               Normal  Normal Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic    Diabetic

            ENST00000000233_at  572.9789041 459.3909055 518.7346032 634.3073455 121.4796009 392.5655477 349.9167019 763.4317554 522.7444017 575.2597527 615.1100166 930.3672619 513.2820896 676.5671934 571.0900458 426.4290491 403.413807  615.2992352 492.6254713 565.5417554 168.8507549 237.4987708 542.7434566 483.832151  491.8789003 497.9534413 365.4595318 704.6730921 450.6708898 876.9633781 550.9539509 541.6934444 420.9490539 414.9382733 721.2788022 303.8027336 518.320268  475.1115461 553.910686  387.3529137 551.9035418 214.8067096 637.4848627 740.4932594 680.4771483 396.3287559 508.4284352 410.3379895 566.2712497 457.7310649 688.2688053 409.6792537 454.9892928 355.4845396 560.5133688 489.2327761 572.0083114 423.037774  446.0659206 671.4156201 571.7261206 458.7748162 569.8088408 416.8074605 452.0319562 368.2152033 282.7670557 397.6284502 534.3118671 445.7642941 506.1687237 561.4900963 487.0378528 408.9051777 377.2237525 499.3149051 918.8325872 341.5624229 466.8511492 482.4019598 400.6427054 521.4207039 441.641977  431.1578234 471.0005611 434.8499401 468.781902  608.0231735 384.5596533 481.861525  527.5575409 537.1398852
            ENST00000000412_at  182.9134858 311.2790547 328.1466205 284.661201  309.1423215 260.7450505 221.5740608 397.3244075 267.2008585 369.4362142 272.2113694 448.6941656 311.6434476 117.9568547 142.3631348 403.1140445 287.1489521 321.3831028 271.4649361 280.2186024 227.9937382 266.6256984 180.9780811 227.9665578 284.9887617 364.6875313 321.7842575 301.7008532 124.1957332 100.9707994 214.1450916 237.7275085 173.7697537 297.6478583 63.61857226 359.0275545 144.0160497 17.66871808 304.2211519 336.4067199 129.2869727 280.7954973 53.93638292 149.8237998 337.1181547 245.6439586 218.0115618 265.541763  287.5904545 157.3008183 219.7857034 161.6206916 392.9445426 224.5839457 308.8055166 435.4570988 266.0918663 250.7688193 257.7053719 269.4951821 137.9425436 262.1354113 108.8681526 287.1398706 220.5283004 148.9247189 358.3710777 438.2380835 258.4216758 282.0532943 83.93634436 193.7729131 226.870373  309.9268168 247.7102424 87.64041724 251.5881076 315.2130252 236.1516353 220.101841  157.2245303 175.1168351 347.5559531 258.5514942 180.5173407 183.4571027 265.269137  230.5085706 309.8478844 234.393803  264.5282872 354.2502918
            ENST00000000442_at  680.273659  773.2983066 714.873634  677.9541305 564.7524183 521.9997432 749.3179886 550.8742073 408.9999339 644.1695935 476.0630578 900.9132454 479.5704423 908.9266123 830.1087897 523.1945301 425.6421093 583.4201303 540.5081117 672.4360643 560.3064793 669.3040441 582.3666036 508.9926698 753.3139362 1037.4114   655.905045  663.2473374 583.6459307 640.4369483 614.7725753 673.7726175 485.9480887 537.6618065 649.2988401 565.7523484 626.6925814 453.935217  563.4013109 601.1991519 587.2127689 421.0348889 518.8518813 850.4326164 910.8674799 673.8070803 725.3674507 495.2819213 624.2359241 638.2594512 509.0428665 676.5986796 589.4659514 562.8653408 580.6616902 668.7699962 725.6712555 508.8585452 377.4074473 580.7475666 574.6932091 466.5785229 638.9159997 813.2603817 451.6879053 1008.11065  706.2653953 583.049544  665.760718  529.0001312 373.7702585 524.0113727 532.6549927 579.1188067 728.9813968 741.5547792 825.4083306 601.6949538 734.2304707 743.4098622 718.9592891 706.1929386 510.2720824 573.5073815 623.6678774 664.5258126 625.9879774 789.902611  624.0243906 733.9235898 629.9337017 580.5212056
            ENST00000001008_at  343.9820997 499.0534233 592.6394506 545.3849448 576.6873648 475.1077999 440.4897057 479.2107103 614.9153965 390.1613084 457.3281255 431.9958666 436.677294  448.3719164 630.8689321 522.3336231 265.1712144 648.7972661 560.5651709 602.0918493 664.8451533 364.2141297 514.2338649 436.4704428 528.4019596 283.7967767 537.1817931 429.5396518 394.4914953 887.409266  607.465471  697.8886414 641.9976729 599.1265234 314.1046167 631.0276676 441.2883961 377.643491  574.2979207 634.4542641 428.0746003 713.7084282 680.4921224 596.0604724 527.8567431 450.9290492 636.2378295 653.5528444 407.0396973 465.6127057 427.9566464 428.3342746 509.9800474 394.7711549 449.4043517 592.3510647 461.5283903 503.9094771 432.4057033 466.1980636 472.0235337 419.8555672 773.4730214 567.2938081 573.6693633 387.3537208 330.9690855 364.4461853 488.1567843 722.2059057 543.8825547 453.1319865 506.0697341 397.1010385 633.1222081 448.3777997 501.1891576 688.4568905 409.5326029 590.1302877 454.2854835 538.0247367 643.6631035 464.1526374 561.5611578 540.2379895 282.914654  775.2773812 593.3579116 477.36216   433.7326825 526.3231224
            ENST00000002125_at  503.0618201 466.8696934 468.7975374 474.4789821 487.694386  544.5300263 396.7141304 454.0083272 615.0314568 431.6497427 438.1188731 383.4778018 468.2330537 460.5393197 556.224184  514.4902498 523.6236532 331.159779  396.1322869 445.9158141 516.4296216 504.771919  402.0168623 465.7008354 480.7486308 439.9315514 490.0051011 590.7356238 440.4756974 478.7506821 495.1563184 601.5274159 384.1548165 429.949611  455.6767029 443.6049687 522.0986563 371.2376253 389.2704212 573.4626181 544.4226763 465.9488816 433.6391364 406.8324175 416.91636   572.5370083 461.5587716 482.0844118 454.6214681 501.1250962 513.9631189 397.4029744 477.848851  504.3434593 469.3388812 415.9512304 397.9654644 352.8174933 595.8210109 481.907706  498.1132384 576.4055377 453.3332804 464.6305123 358.8449041 518.9092188 539.2399574 395.9907669 460.6024325 357.5305813 489.7344525 459.9637779 546.0771339 487.6606465 505.7651607 478.9104657 420.9891195 564.6675594 489.0172893 779.0568937 443.6353183 419.7201189 467.0440722 628.6534673 370.4476402 438.5878543 441.1076573 581.4685652 490.6893518 388.4432167 402.3869946 340.8459868
            ENST00000002165_at  381.4236801 362.264353  354.5074732 266.1748622 281.2178835 311.6680282 345.352818  386.9079409 215.1275261 405.1089327 268.2371698 302.1285753 240.5965851 375.7655728 261.0174281 274.8486268 256.7583925 342.6249426 252.5655984 267.9519894 186.4135771 286.0999667 276.9908829 343.8186636 317.0879263 153.3394509 220.9848162 489.6903681 268.4918121 448.811033  286.5267389 273.5635211 255.2466108 222.4098616 360.7530909 174.5121225 381.2834069 448.6939959 370.8036897 504.8076749 334.0499077 216.2859058 295.1211221 664.2419915 361.674462  254.0853347 378.1930652 383.7620562 349.4674921 131.1689144 329.6636765 260.0710541 289.623985  230.0437197 223.8619568 234.5741104 319.8014527 241.1088727 238.7491967 333.2616169 215.248265  278.7124337 189.8288623 163.7912823 303.9614998 313.0820322 490.8983665 381.1688287 242.6785358 371.8860799 262.0845988 261.1745378 415.3072537 250.1704962 229.4901794 245.346469  226.6996264 338.7119919 322.0200728 392.9025476 288.8625465 362.8941856 253.7819    594.003985  313.4971831 256.1988251 223.4384366 513.2764271 254.7458044 378.4451143 274.7541502 433.7009417
            ENST00000002501_at  230.8670797 29.46732917 409.2949489 328.4450351 302.3324906 293.2717445 267.4416355 178.5378562 383.2413981 82.58942741 315.4905298 328.8759839 141.4126107 213.2450961 342.2747868 167.7489541 269.3160832 442.586569  108.5216242 214.6646031 267.0681476 268.9714176 399.9405611 328.3373169 189.4036824 467.4451413 243.2388978 168.0454875 307.5784318 475.3053663 320.2874426 269.5111733 262.2882297 295.3962488 284.5476789 164.0112937 279.3626515 96.30469016 311.7722258 274.8946401 236.8008324 363.8601784 308.7661407 189.6486997 200.49359   333.3682245 190.1077898 75.48097002 232.4937169 284.6354251 245.035352  266.054617  409.4959293 548.2560319 270.8543248 217.0270997 378.3931578 453.7098378 445.1662101 269.51351   519.5795878 216.142864  344.3332959 429.4077984 391.0258611 161.6415428 84.64639287 157.1836474 381.124423  412.3619797 296.5524285 395.5207694 333.8268037 251.4301787 383.2264701 216.4195489 259.9904897 260.8493497 333.0134213 481.373763  218.2290516 544.6097984 359.4325748 303.2138296 205.7693552 106.0268745 312.2996588 501.7705928 323.4923205 308.6125647 388.8604185 236.5215406
            ENST00000002829_at  199.0038566 121.6503751 182.7876193 195.2723077 183.4864242 228.1838286 189.3409331 225.9621779 332.0557115 204.6866245 284.7849172 237.5834175 211.3205773 228.8543475 172.3804016 162.0788762 180.0364059 173.6512539 152.6771835 109.1466489 279.1983744 148.5789343 127.6912971 109.4897917 160.1699807 228.8627105 128.6900274 278.1014683 156.6055855 242.6168253 221.2038821 215.591159  142.8829405 215.8637024 251.0447655 138.215042  187.7021363 274.1236845 198.6071969 178.0714625 176.9110707 275.6981144 270.7028879 279.4227805 266.846999  203.54459   271.8767431 163.186003  228.6355415 179.8757088 52.14996654 215.5586768 210.9677553 156.9934618 171.9942949 282.6909635 268.4345143 160.0669638 189.1180934 220.8863192 157.4002578 201.1109324 298.0042124 164.7178985 187.6397644 221.3765855 161.312136  141.4963387 168.9270118 213.9650135 341.3549072 157.0862921 243.6330136 135.6649087 129.7846036 294.4694468 127.1957528 193.4093888 100.3539848 302.0415893 149.7245314 155.9635611 197.3551493 202.1575837 189.5009374 227.781952  183.9815511 270.6051644 149.7654533 219.4156472 199.2316676 153.1876162
            ENST00000003100_at  327.1075241 392.6686634 345.2583347 339.2739271 327.7556639 484.6402616 570.020593  369.6017606 676.8500251 520.5894633 648.5147514 157.4064504 409.9759816 470.4382692 227.6089806 469.4710927 562.3280511 296.0752489 548.7545926 124.3642277 477.3702938 313.0407919 283.4985431 377.5007652 263.5804564 171.6471324 213.9884458 296.0109118 186.7891021 414.8000507 661.2421103 728.2615936 581.7935877 410.8886655 374.6633307 279.2649416 494.2296579 420.9811677 153.3223848 504.6747862 420.2587252 652.4356506 656.5721455 960.8873587 474.2530611 460.3442491 468.021216  365.8700445 333.1680053 700.4898    759.1574842 380.3376985 226.3884    566.2894535 451.0800354 514.8862295 753.336113  545.4031077 482.1789458 507.2927509 489.1243119 360.1919778 537.5107745 357.4014945 513.8197772 764.6571984 822.4425474 410.0671164 365.7718156 308.86269   865.5236082 409.419174  525.0834335 407.252456  257.7077025 721.8848941 449.0225637 420.3792371 405.194522  857.4608966 223.1693829 610.8036867 304.3407932 324.4848409 558.2994986 417.3384256 720.7905027 677.1006216 101.3565637 312.7675518 742.2214418 410.0593415
            ENST00000003302_at  637.9012189 670.1002194 539.7070533 564.4869815 587.7587819 612.0094465 611.5993706 679.7712926 672.9780506 629.0004999 790.5300379 450.1517632 548.3692435 390.1564098 572.7564141 653.0767613 691.0231051 609.9171229 874.8037713 809.9319403 754.9763905 803.4011012 789.4612227 656.3846664 760.1216213 1059.922641 670.096094  726.4253516 438.3560742 889.0903634 604.6693087 632.3388487 819.0712865 678.101194  423.3659563 751.0164721 660.0484789 544.2575809 861.2559221 761.2962504 611.6166971 751.3660072 587.1270042 850.9246038 785.9387979 728.1352335 486.3079242 845.9663685 817.5623147 630.9137349 815.055616  482.3435947 823.7593149 485.9869118 687.0560881 923.2339676 485.6267407 700.1760702 699.426071  516.0442628 754.1597317 764.3876993 503.1719447 799.2079937 697.8082115 514.3142897 567.295561  744.1735196 658.02604   603.5961395 601.258473  989.091891  669.8768003 827.9917332 709.6976276 611.0617806 955.2846934 576.6749576 578.5395254 878.6113735 750.9826304 927.585574  776.3381764 917.4133204 719.3974454 474.4760595 721.4619961 841.9047804 664.7559389 550.5618088 820.1473249 874.5983072
            ENST00000003583_at  31.04268484 43.65710183 116.7092304 8.851931946 50.58736371 11.10363715 61.59874076 80.90280145 30.80845989 90.89089556 43.22604875 111.2486876 69.81118086 48.15354885 95.58769562 9.796762465 84.64031043 39.09067642 21.01163888 40.82772371 16.86841941 47.52701853 18.3081951  23.75411329 27.54614478 73.09677877 41.90723487 81.82408265 20.14262971 18.593321   11.31958042 17.62517321 28.50068582 36.58239672 101.95165   56.68631155 34.60350716 86.80287078 32.6993325  16.31018008 12.00160566 15.23728874 14.48137366 74.23737635 26.64320885 10.11162008 46.19183445 97.44355584 17.06874548 9.623324827 74.06428165 8.161565427 115.345678  6.418300148 77.11540601 11.15160745 30.67200121 27.64107287 9.811009473 108.7203402 20.80376474 50.38592116 17.8533836  123.3034001 72.01762537 11.42842191 16.29453823 52.46161562 12.73331754 24.68363062 12.377754   14.43052184 7.798930166 22.50223851 23.8605083  37.29070581 43.62508625 60.58836225 64.88998552 20.93492087 49.39280122 129.6312602 51.17998062 27.11796284 102.7458807 72.06858716 36.6200901  27.24114629 127.1983367 64.22482216 70.06286598 75.27998259
            ENST00000003607_at  2267.93938  2137.960603 2081.201027 2405.400445 2131.551739 1582.445965 2814.884195 1834.104683 1945.560966 1984.798068 1987.862874 2884.011781 1804.953329 2069.442954 2228.187807 1879.334961 1618.075734 2316.786889 2155.466195 1887.941764 1890.685425 2033.853821 2135.056943 1986.298738 2143.540676 1775.400369 2051.173384 2127.612368 2407.490985 2430.430133 1852.529002 1983.824112 2188.931817 2088.401155 2412.02495  1791.432028 1944.315583 1692.164834 2239.48958  2057.871172 1791.41752  1974.123107 1793.491276 1545.712168 2297.90511  1893.598653 2111.743725 1681.724182 2198.754306 2049.160429 2548.989104 1909.765338 2172.825175 1868.216026 2015.04783  1917.198906 2218.204021 1711.925641 2114.101434 1866.087605 2125.294283 1866.245915 2162.375625 1415.638502 1520.386986 2709.694284 1448.294578 1963.868344 1856.624957 1936.104099 2081.16567  2187.127946 1840.355302 1764.99901  2147.29338  1939.691022 1962.685635 1984.672154 1809.422849 2142.888364 2218.622747 2174.006883 1939.104393 2241.796527 2028.564723 2174.782435 2025.481145 2251.26161  1854.985208 2047.980459 2022.942844 1993.390211
            ENST00000003912_at  232.0764701 197.3018476 162.1834403 114.6211708 43.00217335 180.7930705 160.5973778 155.4195646 250.2062136 68.095829   123.2954363 244.5677181 134.7204807 201.7433056 150.9282922 208.5045049 126.7135864 209.3353582 115.1908219 173.517538  198.4738347 164.0722068 160.132345  126.7220409 112.1420186 158.3514601 203.6449695 239.2315994 140.8968109 250.1119973 173.8979167 245.4746712 205.1739089 100.2391061 200.0678256 166.5841671 136.0596663 136.6032998 121.3559173 142.5552851 203.3439402 190.5871722 64.81424325 214.0509626 117.8184305 161.8376623 170.9915609 203.9683965 68.67959148 201.4034463 98.05126631 130.7274902 122.8095112 136.8121112 89.60721647 50.95884019 177.2168375 72.07502759 165.4524791 160.4424377 71.35335593 151.2775306 66.96369697 174.8104332 136.7238705 315.7529451 228.0117099 210.1320235 209.3718238 138.9775586 149.4926677 48.13749396 136.5030414 105.6170447 74.53902289 116.9442397 161.9110211 155.5261492 121.4729804 247.998044  82.1183493  65.57905965 185.7627671 176.1824872 111.1210537 177.9942076 151.9704576 279.4268797 148.6862841 168.1029757 211.8475691 147.8773196
            ENST00000004531_at  786.1785139 791.4509307 1037.277304 565.0646109 760.8185104 960.6283153 781.0866144 870.7070319 1233.095092 725.5217069 811.1144067 892.2601785 756.7658252 558.2109463 603.4228668 639.0624255 766.4059697 477.4673826 1015.728604 748.2272297 1034.847796 1025.512841 832.8412198 972.4800859 864.4234387 769.323633  778.6157875 539.1110387 665.904595  1272.714504 641.6174688 498.7207905 621.7606515 632.7284064 684.6735023 819.5172946 725.1320797 602.4051106 719.9389669 835.0680291 920.4622344 1157.148209 923.2621628 866.753194  800.7290022 658.5546283 722.1288125 634.8586885 680.6385108 594.5393883 699.166434  752.3215565 1380.599729 825.9806644 809.0853402 1092.64361  742.4596897 759.5221257 753.9214073 592.0272502 811.3504174 704.8593798 821.2014837 558.9420479 712.0370768 657.604529  915.133609  1078.959684 655.9728191 1014.750313 1410.815324 873.5427217 722.0563672 717.4461904 808.6127937 786.9952271 889.8322208 597.6643641 454.3936997 700.8383679 711.5762858 788.5553278 873.3763509 635.978739  574.5040711 696.3670391 773.9744865 838.9292558 811.4645538 844.6112168 626.3544317 870.4828805
            ENST00000004921_at  21.38606244 82.82773119 22.8223966  88.2777636  69.77938111 56.56680516 78.71116597 101.0564561 38.24686115 34.82741833 38.60922291 102.7488908 29.05782292 145.8010143 123.4276794 21.57245656 37.9414392  34.99250078 22.17804299 106.0451702 98.51408956 80.16883823 82.49799563 79.44329714 67.62106306 52.22606634 123.1581125 151.9158097 21.34614525 78.83102281 166.8023919 84.79170976 159.5345815 74.09550363 42.14692686 125.1493818 85.90127479 48.34074248 16.70954396 92.56919751 136.598421  111.5725611 35.43518801 188.6827007 103.0328351 26.79040515 28.45874877 107.9839263 143.5742308 88.06933072 87.85108109 111.1399815 18.06285319 70.22176076 101.3709952 89.51325679 111.1267322 29.82276276 26.80777635 56.65034041 133.189805  12.10612252 133.2440927 72.23810425 92.03547651 82.43598242 33.909166   129.0943042 156.4181884 98.989857   95.24968274 58.74083476 74.65548875 140.3885078 118.0751082 51.06305778 184.5449198 107.5486973 937.3529459 80.58174756 43.19581496 125.6134182 77.29183797 120.3447845 17.70710139 63.87669118 67.79564532 191.6326412 81.71083331 28.11278475 106.9707974 112.0734332
            ENST00000004980_at  146.0289691 89.96407969 59.51961811 92.98087332 111.8789279 156.1262912 136.9700475 152.9916712 186.120169  121.7360867 95.33793086 110.4660418 69.87998503 100.8626234 131.0547959 99.72195765 93.76513864 92.63585917 151.2070622 155.6623482 156.7808225 102.1482932 138.4615911 142.7384473 131.9650752 117.4172625 72.71950059 107.1641648 119.9280964 104.2004432 116.4797515 107.6796257 124.5090988 87.05976167 83.02784365 131.9649195 110.3811482 119.477614  101.0238794 82.30269988 113.8234849 110.3779475 137.562547  218.3617882 89.64718198 93.42518217 60.43694255 85.26645852 115.7448611 73.76898406 157.938668  149.194182  155.1580312 120.4574069 115.2285363 144.6048563 126.0254893 146.0708471 81.77014469 78.72782992 170.3284364 129.4436084 134.7005028 138.1363153 78.67916308 111.5831655 155.2360987 69.85847393 131.6364853 151.3324125 129.9244935 118.071756  149.2178582 105.4018055 97.08958713 144.7052488 142.8637699 94.56506025 124.0529621 162.2246315 68.20069805 120.2276243 80.74758033 152.5120596 142.9506448 100.6834322 174.6145109 128.4906627 88.57422384 81.18200935 166.6201654 90.00465192
            ENST00000004982_at  3774.618958 5861.392988 4429.949896 4459.446236 3126.984245 5849.849289 4980.065803 4659.783669 2713.010017 4412.026918 2546.265648 9462.12731  2714.836384 4241.248113 4759.231502 2924.02148  2476.160775 8656.333575 3560.927553 4622.174096 4782.785468 7111.097158 4521.94249  4321.518735 5534.941173 6579.729701 6272.664289 7257.861465 2395.125983 2861.22546  2219.343959 3611.240934 2790.896887 3699.459657 1693.918086 3558.771018 3122.362435 1750.310995 6367.581809 2941.894882 3258.023414 2472.384202 1876.133451 2081.024867 4090.159777 4118.118687 4574.789686 4940.663197 4926.179777 2374.737689 2799.113778 1433.146582 2809.443216 3080.111481 4702.670653 4487.117779 2308.301386 2341.178376 2470.838236 6113.586402 2753.110095 2812.821773 1935.737965 4429.589396 2725.804391 2460.87378  1965.735642 3085.63008  2145.390494 2594.121254 1808.86516  2394.981677 2606.088173 2722.349836 4676.303232 2163.826559 5061.641847 3201.77325  4595.601363 3397.684537 4719.980513 2982.586631 5538.669319 4329.540439 3774.100987 4768.594655 3027.691895 3883.329398 3195.396527 3642.924751 2637.698362 3728.41533
            ENST00000005082_at  453.5692874 422.690832  523.7766994 444.7101032 352.8383287 423.3924895 468.9032867 333.4750543 281.3873368 345.7944956 233.7242126 560.3748164 538.3554354 362.3488839 372.1797984 520.6977282 531.8102017 252.1468501 394.0808689 423.0152865 547.2817171 481.9020498 405.0430049 400.8629157 458.932446  629.4491384 396.7265715 506.2468699 341.479482  513.9036449 330.2478062 555.367855  419.1158694 389.709882  331.3956664 423.464309  458.6492861 173.1116269 429.0620713 394.1857874 454.3746898 519.0275276 135.6459919 500.46113   467.9892213 441.60694   428.8051657 388.8533428 512.5996522 468.2589432 542.3702934 406.5916627 447.5088706 565.525008  441.4437813 458.5293348 320.6068235 545.7062262 342.5332658 525.1504686 435.1543576 574.0124178 212.0670789 457.3280087 503.4233653 308.2054217 688.7036685 431.3390728 443.4339618 380.4182084 540.5183999 554.0810117 439.9011104 340.6880171 406.9617148 419.5673786 531.0696388 416.2012229 398.7452807 351.7492984 490.7309288 595.1230762 422.9125569 533.0440219 394.290979  348.8974332 479.540974  336.0048949 466.0816219 441.7102016 593.6519146 498.0693919
            ENST00000005178_at  4693.778037 2201.913981 7583.105259 4490.535047 2538.613727 12107.36649 4393.392484 3090.449746 1280.462306 2940.34807  14633.04864 4348.418829 13993.962   1437.021992 4976.322369 2162.359929 2042.069412 1388.198227 8875.706317 4253.010222 6354.823924 2684.699661 6737.812703 4060.608135 3257.158063 9861.045686 3939.177142 3570.69402  6249.842711 3219.280809 6629.250741 3971.50203  1622.441379 3045.185254 3388.053955 5619.099412 4193.813626 777.9814831 2580.174714 11902.69695 3123.472894 1155.769363 1136.726942 3045.212388 1989.812175 5717.484181 1178.370362 4397.111638 8435.197754 4806.448232 3335.178822 10760.56237 13033.22571 1933.119203 4619.177057 2648.816104 5245.282668 6149.175344 2761.94197  3492.866067 3086.728076 6779.017002 1439.422051 4989.369795 9561.483861 6213.41873  4503.174864 3429.477634 9650.69583  3418.051652 21840.116   1940.815622 4467.098616 7362.819813 7088.393538 7287.721411 8080.408321 4118.290084 5138.197563 1849.653087 6008.517983 13846.56128 11789.91765 4039.041257 1990.97374  4360.392223 3168.546472 6860.977343 12606.52895 4546.410244 4684.698084 8395.458241
            ENST00000005198_at  36.93114297 53.568692   116.9028713 88.2625159  120.5955294 50.08493573 47.82115526 154.8325745 229.7318164 148.0681788 31.32770562 79.98229339 137.3952589 89.07415687 82.38668872 93.21824326 114.7052896 74.99954686 120.7881741 169.0196675 35.72903198 155.4634978 104.8014734 119.0244273 78.4143691  178.3702682 8.501686449 68.52673405 84.40023942 283.4170159 88.35435873 109.2135462 146.5488924 13.55436052 60.71121576 70.77151415 105.2549168 80.22455943 41.52219792 76.87640695 142.0793133 225.3453988 71.4121492  434.013967  19.03099682 73.25077586 28.98678212 120.4458476 94.94362927 90.72840865 100.8189004 98.83674338 101.7372204 64.97833767 67.89846219 53.19266542 92.20559575 23.29648255 76.03027186 101.5937481 105.65783   93.00692478 229.4691666 29.13029224 100.6477161 156.4119654 20.62233014 102.2714329 105.1121457 211.2101593 182.8644303 208.2458674 80.7685605  103.5204445 215.7926386 11.15918031 83.43106193 88.70816667 10.68738082 134.8763544 9.754536044 25.305996   148.1291824 80.40964921 134.5998176 160.287079  81.5266728  184.1147645 50.68516119 52.51676701 127.2758423 198.5077285
            ENST00000005226_at  163.9185753 14.28959499 73.72589939 64.76029282 18.6962353  81.93597203 102.3650551 114.5981253 40.28210574 34.72375955 28.30378465 30.51151686 48.67542479 76.50714897 126.7190231 10.7104151  45.18089117 26.1950976  110.6201937 42.50744545 70.84378    95.88281936 89.62959547 160.2608828 77.69423071 45.30179954 85.8878121  74.26405303 115.3378581 30.89748713 44.72316783 81.32129449 108.8397183 43.18302832 138.2638455 30.31104682 10.846405   23.92578733 58.66846861 6.509845061 15.95860908 54.77430157 109.6810886 104.6049169 30.60217401 22.9758795  90.42562422 85.01516612 68.44378028 88.37921024 70.26926145 79.67245046 75.30362341 60.60739788 86.28421862 30.55712935 94.34162372 72.83126798 108.6382379 49.54386658 38.73245579 50.64117167 156.9650255 124.5785416 104.4403454 128.9607607 140.5003458 116.0667711 120.9350395 34.62663287 128.3623245 123.5924231 33.14393616 100.0497368 22.08982613 58.82554729 36.25793751 128.7036886 13.66549505 58.76537962 104.6704322 77.83035292 48.86460317 72.94170131 60.14440277 34.44273249 24.85323945 57.97596123 96.4946603  15.41344522 77.46442564 15.29951456
            ENST00000005257_at  757.6660863 872.4387185 766.2527906 833.2788024 994.3533238 928.193112  955.4885983 831.2328925 694.1126556 1283.272147 956.7197132 669.7172247 758.7033578 756.0791194 1194.69647  604.9470248 976.7839403 643.9421572 706.13526   592.5896129 797.4449654 795.7157262 739.836703  684.4097308 794.700911  884.5198034 817.7267483 607.2466142 1197.613856 586.0357288 994.5043444 1364.00005  948.3019719 840.4392026 1298.617602 749.8087798 1160.1656   863.1613599 769.9540763 966.9839446 681.5531284 586.129115  1474.186843 973.4540919 776.6583289 932.0081916 864.3738653 753.6455051 607.1430249 820.0057388 1031.550523 947.9357294 673.1957482 920.8121675 561.2125074 626.5905202 1120.786163 971.7522064 1058.865864 567.9017726 964.7112197 928.3704126 891.9054168 1025.244871 922.9319499 1149.215077 686.8504985 623.8993372 1044.105335 904.5354247 535.1955375 791.5501434 939.8123562 778.5550947 863.6014391 800.3328698 754.6923237 972.6153152 994.0159225 969.6219768 639.141327  639.883427  869.3858867 1044.116974 810.9100692 1107.659051 675.3390611 754.3996365 927.3694448 745.3571854 715.5082311 675.9047584
            ENST00000005259_at  1962.054608 1529.752343 1355.487522 1395.243978 1353.726454 1413.55515  1653.633529 1470.100128 1358.416608 962.604889  1008.668047 1288.656349 1435.761696 1112.122723 1547.289175 2105.743205 2059.405262 924.0198858 1450.034855 1782.819019 1657.613897 1771.720901 1875.254517 1742.33436  1751.064934 1673.593648 1613.311531 1675.01971  1207.503879 1234.01959  1788.466323 1701.315687 1731.358163 1404.547698 1237.342997 1696.302472 1748.866388 1151.694987 1529.042044 1612.655161 1760.175873 1450.839968 1093.498894 657.0354798 1372.629158 1890.876039 1340.115959 1247.52129  1292.56459  2288.215913 1538.70935  1633.314157 1619.595671 2176.372347 1602.721236 1457.225089 1558.98628  1699.530808 1957.962894 1371.662581 1588.644699 1691.522556 1161.731749 1679.43577  1449.370732 1582.880088 2075.565258 2067.521838 1744.977942 1225.932725 1447.064176 1820.938302 1967.446526 1982.423671 1749.267457 1305.567252 1803.40069  1360.405131 1958.448937 1789.590202 1642.85515  1610.068438 1695.524664 1879.541764 1919.771208 1148.232539 2053.761939 1691.759322 1755.031665 1855.767259 2013.535953 1201.229405
            ENST00000005260_at  74.94539933 57.76438778 129.4884702 12.86103516 68.96195271 131.9380522 130.881999  106.8419025 26.44096646 41.60434077 98.17166408 12.93055108 53.80679688 14.78552483 162.0994706 28.04985947 59.67678263 13.54801572 20.45168867 40.60094843 31.41019296 108.0475405 19.47130325 99.61109903 82.05794731 71.61523771 116.6934982 88.25487422 71.12662352 17.32473798 85.64888014 54.69331151 162.4878675 18.76172769 102.3335272 106.6872661 20.31602086 20.26768103 117.3132637 66.08754759 10.59841559 151.783361  18.59428848 134.5109322 26.978309   13.52201901 138.0965471 54.28035196 13.14474159 44.74510147 17.73653224 13.50642622 22.13623771 28.45523138 13.42113294 60.46916961 16.51944502 95.45663493 49.74091592 102.1075259 16.52710322 20.25775757 20.56940992 77.49209532 44.67263906 45.61347853 17.77047594 20.27249407 17.11585882 23.42521125 106.0561078 77.14718233 60.20397843 8.716713058 15.09786822 38.95742435 78.47843244 12.80261599 43.66265632 107.9397021 16.74843135 44.7795684  14.01793351 45.05102026 109.1556721 65.78138822 40.62064269 65.11694672 15.91414335 77.6613971  11.02548016 125.0821208
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: I'm analysing microarrays from raw results andI'll calculate z-score for each tag for all of the samples, teratments and controls together.Nevertheless I've never done calculation such like these. What do you mean by standardise? As I suppose your signal values are already  after normalization, show some example data. What is type of your microarray? Illumina, Affymetrix? If you want to check differences in expression between controls - treatments I've to recommend classic fold change and then log fold change calculation.

Comment: @Adamm  I update the post .

Comment: @Adamm I want to standarise the expression ( mean=0 and sd=1) by using z-score I want to find the normal distribution not the Fold change

Comment: Ok I udnestand, I'll calculate the z-score for the whole chip as it is described here http://pedagogix-tagc.univ-mrs.fr/courses/statistics_bioinformatics/practicals/microarray_standardization.html